# Why can't I run my own modules for D&D Adventurers League?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

D&D Adventurers League requires DMs to stick to published modules.  I understand this from the perspective of restricting super-powerful magic items or some DM giving ridiculous XP or gold.  However, they could have just said

> #### Tier 1 per 2 hours play
>
> - Maximum XP = X
> - Maximum Gold  = X
> - Maximum Magic Items: 1 uncommon magic item per 4 hours play,
>
> #### Tier 2
>
> ...

… allowing DMs to create their own material. Does anyone know the rationale behind this Adventurers League decision?

Comment: Wow, why is this question so bad?

Comment: It's likely because it's a straight forward question that some might view as obvious that it attracted the first few downvotes. After that there is a tendency for them to just pile up. Don't take it too much to heart.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### D&D Adventure League is the official campaign

From the [website](http://dnd.wizards.com/playevents/organized-play), "The D&D Adventurers League is an ongoing official campaign for Dungeons & Dragons". This means that the setting, story arcs, NPCs, and everything else that goes into the modules is backed by Wizards as part of an official canon. Letting DMs create their own modules and insert them into the official canon would create problems with consistency.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if a DM who designs his own adventure misjudges how quickly the party is able to progress through the challenges he creates?  The party might end up earning significantly more (or less) than the prescribed amount of XP/gold in a given 2 hour session.

What if the DM makes an error, either in reading a monster's stats incorrectly, or a math error in designing the challenge, such that the players SHOULD be entitled to more than X gold or Y XP at the end of a given 2 hour session?  The battle is already over; the monsters defeated.  Are the players just shafted out of their due rewards because they exceeded the League's limit?

What if the players decide they want to go off and do something completely unrelated to the adventure the DM created?  When everything is homebrew, some players might develop a sense of entitlement that they can do what they want.  If all players and DMs understand that the adventures are pre-made, it helps cut down on the impulse to ignore the adventure and go off on a tangent.

On top of all that, you're invariably going to get *some DMs* who give out way too much XP/gold/items and then say "oops" when someone from the League calls them out on it.  Maybe he's a pushover who gives in to his friends too easily.  Maybe he gets carried away and forgets the limits the League imposes.  Maybe he's just an idiot.  What then?  The party just magically loses an appropriate amount of kit (and/or characters levels) after so many sessions because an official from the League caught on?  That sort of situation is going to generate all sorts of mistrust and animosity towards the League, even though it's not their fault that the DM couldn't follow simple orders.

Comment: "What if the DM makes an error, ... in reading a monster's stats incorrectly" is a problem unrelated to creating a module.  Even a DM running an official module could read a monster's stats wrong.

Comment: @LegendaryDude Its not the misreading this answer points at, it's the problem cause by consequently going over the question's proposed XP limit as a result of misreading.